# Pourquoi est-ce qu'on ne peut dire "vous voudriez"?

Tags: grammaire

Je suis en train de traduire un document de l'anglais au français. L'expression originale est :

> How would you like to (...)?

Moi, je l'aurais traduite avec *Comment voudriez-vous ...*, mais [Google Translate](https://translate.google.it/#en/fr/How%20would%20you%20like%20to) affirme que la seule traduction correcte est *Comment aimeriez-vous ...*.

En faisant des recherches, j'ai aussi trouvé que la traduction de *You would like* est *Vous souhaitez*, et non *Vous voudriez*.

Pourquoi est-ce qu'on ne peut pas dire *Vous voudriez*, ni dans les questions, ni dans les affirmations ?

Comment: Utiliser le verbe vouloir est tout à fait possible. Tout dépend du contexte.

Comment: J'ajouterai, par ailleurs, qu'il ne faut pas faire une confiance aveugle à google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Comment voudriez-vous ...* est tout à fait correcte.

La difficulté de la traduction anglo-française tient dans la *reformulation* : le mot à mot est à proscrire pour les textes soutenus.

Selon l'univers de l'auteur, selon le contexte textuel votre solution est :

- parfaite, si l'auteur insiste sur l'intention de *volonté* du locuteur.
- inadaptée, si c'est le *désir*, l'*envie*, ou même l'*amour* non charnel que l'on évoque ; *Comment aimeriez-vous* est mieux adapté aux situations affectives.

Il n'y a pas d'interdit entre ces solutions, seulement une 'couleur', une 'saveur' différente, l'intelligibilité n'est pas en jeu.

Answer (score 2):

C'est correct.

*Vous voudriez* est le conditionnel du verbe vouloir à la deuxième personne du pluriel, et aucune exception ne vient l'en empêcher dans ce cas-ci.

Google Translate n'est pas un outil fiable et sa traduction se rapproche du mot à mot, la pire manière de traduire un texte d'une langue vers du français. *Comment aimeriez-vous*, de plus, me semble relativement peu utilisé dans le langage courant, voir incorrect.